# How to use OR in IIF statement in row visibility?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, report-builder

How to use `OR` in `IIF` statement in `SSRS`

```
=IIF((Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
      Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
      Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "School Life" 
      OR 
      "My goal for this term..." 
      OR 
      "Student Reflective Comment", True, False)
```

Its throwing error

Comment: Quick fix: Nest the 3 additional ternary operators. It doesn't look pretty, but it works.

Comment: Please can you post answer? I am using this for `row visibility` show hide expression,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vba
=IIF(Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
     Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
     Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "School Life" 
 OR 
 IIF(Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
     Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
     Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "My goal for this term..." 
 OR 
 IIF(Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
     Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
     Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "Student Reflective Comment"
```

The result is boolean itself and does not need in additional `IIF()`.

Comment: Thanks for response @akina, I am using this for row visibility show hide expression, how can i use this? Where true false in `IIF` ?

Comment: I try this `=IIF((Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
     Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
     Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "School Life", True, False) 
 OR 
 IIF((Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
     Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
     Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "My goal for this term..." ,True, False)
 OR 
 IIF((Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value="",
     Fields!txtSubjectArchivedName.Value,
     Fields!txtCurrentSubjectReportName.Value) = "Student Reflective Comment", True, False)` but it throw error

Comment: Each compare gives boolean value itselt (True or False). Their combining via OR operator gives boolean too. The given code is final and do not need in separate True/False convertion!

Comment: its mean i just need to use above `expr` in visibility show/hide expr in `Row Visibility` ?

Comment: @user192303 o_O of course... or you want to use something like `IIF(variable=True,True,False)`?

Comment: Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you great ! working